# Android - Problem with the Serializable interface

Tags: android, serializable, parcelable

I have been using the `Serializable` interface to pass an object from one activity to another. I am using `putExtra` on the sender side and  `getSerializable` on the receiver side. Everything works fine but I have received (for the first time) the following error report:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading
>   a Serializable object

I don't understand why this exception has been generated since I am using `getSerializable` and not `getParcelable`.

I know that I should implement the `Parcelable` interface instead because it has been designed specifically for Android (and that's what I will end up doing) but I want to understand why I am getting this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parcelable` is mentioned in this error because an `Intent` you send from one `Activity` to another has a `Bundle` inside and this `Bundle` is `Parcelable`. When you call `Intent.putExtra()` this extra is added to the inner `Bundle`. When `Intent` is passed between activities its `Bundle` is converted to and from a byte array and so is your `Serializable` object.

But I don't know why this error occurs. Maybe it's because of some bug in `writeObject()`/`readObject()` implementation.